# SUM Hour and Minutes SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Good day, I was trying to sum Hour and Minutes. But for now i only able to sum `the hour part`

Here is My Query. Yes, i get this query when i put my question in stackoverflow

```
select 
    a.Nip, b.FullName, c.attendancedate, c.inTime, c.OutTime,
    DATEPART(wk, c.attendanceDate) week, 
    case 
       when DATEADD(HOUR, -8, OutTime) <= InTime then '00:00' 
       else CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),DATEADD(HOUR, -8, OutTime - InTime), 108) 
    end AS total  
from 
    DinasHoDetail a 
left join 
    Employee b on a.Nip = b.Nip
left join 
    DinasHoHeader d on a.KodeDinasHeader = d.KodeDinasHeader
left join 
    attendance c on a.Nip = c.Nip and attendancedate between d.startdate and d.enddate
        where a.KodeDinasHeader = 'DN0000001' and b.nip = '1602744'
```

From My Query Above i get this result

[image]

so, as you can see from the result. There is a col called with `week`. So i'm trying to sum every `total` group by week. Here is the query

```
select Nip,sum(ro) achieve,FullName 
from( 
    select a.Nip,b.FullName,DATEPART( wk, c.attendanceDate) week, 
sum(case when DATEADD(HOUR, -8, OutTime) <=InTime then 0 else DATEDIFF(HOUR, InTime, OutTime) - 8 end)/8 AS RO 
from DinasHoDetail a 
    left join Employee b on a.Nip = b.Nip 
    left join DinasHoHeader d on a.KodeDinasHeader = d.KodeDinasHeader 
    left join attendance c on a.Nip =c.Nip and attendancedate between d.startdate and d.enddate 
where a.KodeDinasHeader = 'DN0000001' and b.nip = '1602744'
    group by a.Nip,b.FullName,DATEPART( wk, c.attendanceDate)) q group by Nip ,FullName
```

here is the result

[image]

**The Problem Part.**

As you can see from the first result. week 37 is `08:11 (Eight hours eleven minute)` and week `38` is `10:00 (Ten hours)`.

Every man will get one achievement when the total is more than `08 hours (Group by week)`. So i should have 2 right ?

I believe my problem is because i'm not do `the datadd method for minute`

With my query above i only able to sum the hours not the minute. So my question is how i can `DATEADD` with `HH:MM` format ?

Comment: Change the logic to count minutes instead of hours, add up the minutes, and divide by 60.

Answer (score 1):

You Just need to use `minute`. Give a try this script below.

```
select Nip,sum(ro) achieve,FullName
     from( 
        select a.Nip,b.FullName,DATEPART( wk, c.attendanceDate) week, 
        sum(case 
            when DATEADD(MINUTE, -480, OutTime) <=InTime 
            then 0 
            else DATEDIFF(MINUTE, InTime, OutTime) - 480 end)/480 AS RO 
            from DinasHoDetail a 
                left join Employee b on a.Nip = b.Nip 
                left join DinasHoHeader d on a.KodeDinasHeader = d.KodeDinasHeader 
                left join attendance c on a.Nip =c.Nip and attendancedate 
                between d.startdate and d.enddate 
                where a.KodeDinasHeader = 'DN0000001' 
                group by a.Nip,b.FullName,DATEPART( wk, c.attendanceDate)
            ) q group by Nip ,FullName
```

Answer (score 0):

For summing time periods and displaying in a new format, unfortunately first we have to convert to time difference into minimum meaningful time unit. In your case, we have to calculate time difference in minutes.
Then we have to sum all time periods which are already in minutes.
As last step we will format all this amount in minutes; in a new format HH:MI or HH:MI:SS etc.

Please refer to tutorial [Calculate Time Operations in SQL Server](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/calculate-time-operations-in-sql-server.aspx) for a sample case

You will see a function fn_CalculateTimeInSeconds there 
You need to create a similar for minutes like

```
RETURN DATEPART(mi,@time) + 60 * DATEPART(hh,@time)
```

Then calculate differences if required

The last function you need is similar to fn_CreateTimeFromSeconds which will format calculated time in minutes to HH:MI format

```
Create Function fn_CreateTimeFromMinutes (
 @minutes int
) Returns varchar(5)
BEGIN
Return
 --CAST (
  RIGHT('00' + CAST( (@minutes / 60) as varchar(2)), 2) + ':' +
  RIGHT('00' + CAST( (@minutes % 60) as varchar(2)), 2)
-- as Time)
END 
go
```